# How do I change a field with hook_node_presave()?

Tags: nodes, hooks, 8

In Drupal 7, I was using `hook_node_presave()` to update some hidden fields in a node.

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node){
    if ( CONDITIONS ) {
        $node->field_fieldname['und'][0]['value'] = importantfunction();
    }
}
```

In Drupal 8 I cannot do the same thing. Looking into the object I tried this:

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node){
    if ( CONDITIONS ) {
        $node->values['field_fieldname'][0]['value'];
    } 
}
```

It won't work though. I am aware that a lot have changed in Drupal 8 and I am studying it, but I did not find an answer to this yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit outdated but still a great resource:

http://wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet

Also the documentation on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/1795854

In short, fields are lists of objects that use property and array access magic methods to simplify reading and writing values to them:

```
// Set a value, the field class will decide what to do with it, usually write to the primary property...
$entity->field_fieldname = importantfunction();

// The default property is often called value, but for reference fields, it is target_id, text fields also have a format for example
$entity->field_fieldname->format = 'full_html';

// By default, you access delta 0, you can also set other deltas.
$entity->field_fieldname[1] = importantfunction();

// You can also append a new item, without hardcoding the delta.
$entity->field_fieldname->appendItem(importantfunction());

// Note that when accessing fields, you must always specify the property:
print $entity->field_fieldname->value;
print $entity->field_fieldname[1]->value;

// What basically happens internally for the above is:
$entity->get('field_fieldname')->get(0)->get('value')->getValue();
```

Comment: That's much better!

Answer (score 3):

Probably late here but if anyone is still looking then:

```
function mymodule_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity){
    $entity->set( 'field_fieldname',importantfunction() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a best practice, but I've come to this solution:

```
function mymodule_node_presave(EntityInterface $node){
    $node->field_fieldname->set(0, importantfunction() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer.

With [\Drupal\node\NodeInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeInterface.php/interface/NodeInterface/8.2.x) interface, I'm using that snippet to achieve your needs :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave();
 *
 * @param \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node
 */

function module_name_node_presave(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
    if($node->get('field_name')->getString() != 'search') {
        $node->set('field_name', 'new field value');
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work