# How to change user field value after node form is submitted?

Tags: 8, nodes, forms, hooks

I currently have a user field called `field_reputation` with a default integer value of 0 (if a user registeres).

[image]

The idea is that this field increases when certain actions are executed. For example, when a user publishes a new article, `field_reputation` should be its current value + 10.

I am trying to achieve this using a form hook:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ) {
  if ( TRUE === in_array( $form_id, array( 'node_article_form') ) ) {
    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
        if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
          $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = '_increase_reputation';
        }
      }
}
```

And then this function is called:

```
function _increase_reputation(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Do something here
}
```

However I can't seem to figure out what code should be written in this function.

Comment: That should be done in `hook_node_presave()`, a submit handler is too late as the node is already saved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Clive says, form submit handler is a bit too late. Do it in `hook_node_presave` or `hook_entity_presave`. If you do it in `hook_node_presave`:

1. Check the node type first: `if ($node->bundle() === 'article')`
2. Get the current user:
   `$user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());`
3. Then set the field value: `$value = (int) $user->get('field_reputation')->getString() + 10; $user->set('field_reputation', $value);` (I'm not 100% sure on this code, but I'm sure there are better ways to do it when you have more than 5 minutes :D. Feels dirty to use `getString()` and then type-cast it into `int`)
4. Save the user entity with `$user->save();`

If you use `hook_entity_presave` then you just need to check for the entity type additionally: `$entity->getEntityType->Id() === 'node'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you help me out a little more? I am quite newby at Drupal... I tried using the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/6bst99ut/1/. But it does not work, nor gives me any errors.

Comment: Any updates? :)

Comment: @Rubenxfd, if you're putting that code in `mytheme.theme`, it might not work. Create a new module and put that code in the `.module` file. Also make sure you put `use \Drupal\user\Entity\User` at the top of the module file.

Comment: I have tried adding a custom module like you said, but provided code does nothing :(

Comment: Did you enable your custom module?

Comment: Yes I did, the module is loaded correctly, but when I press "save" when writing an article. The article is published but nothing happens to the user field_reputation. The code in my module: https://jsfiddle.net/gf77gtt6/1/

Comment: What's the current value in `field_reputation`? Can you do some debugging and see where it's failing? What's in `$value` before `$user->set`? Do you get any warnings/errors in your logs? I'm a bit new to D8 myself so hope someone else can chime in.

Comment: Take a look at this answer too: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180388/how-do-i-change-a-field-with-hook-node-presave

Comment: @Rubenxfd I'm sorry, forgot we're changing the user entity and not the node so we need to save the user after changing it with $user->save()